# Automatic deployment of azure chat bot to an application profile using Powershell

Tags: frameworks, bots

I want to automate the deployment process of the chat bot that I have built using microsoft bot framework to azure.

Is there any way to achieve this using Powershell ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What do you mean to "application profile"? Do you want to automate the process to registering bots via Powershell? Do you want to automate the process of deploying your bot to Azure or any other service through Powershell? Or are we talking about integrating your Azure bot with a client application?

Comment: Hi Fracisico, Thanks for your response. I meant publishing profile in this case. I want to automate the process of deploying a bot to Azure or any other service through Powershell. I am aware about the process of continuous deployment, but this process exposes the code. I want to handover the executable ( or something similar to an executable through which the bot could be deployed in prod environments) to the third party and provide them with a powershell script to deploy the code keeping the code secured. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is currently working on this feature and it will be released in a near future. Thanks for your patience!